# Jenkins check property and than execute or not

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Is it possible in jenkins to start a job on a node and before start check if the property or env. variable exists? If it exists start, if it does not exist don't start on it. How can i do this?

I need it, because my first job reverts the virtual machine after executing and make it off in jenkins but in jenkins this node is a little bit time on-line(near 5 sec) and the second job in downstream can catch it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[Script Trigger plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ScriptTrigger+Plugin)** to use a script that will decide whether to trigger a job or not. You've got to write the script though.